# Reduction in public traffic after migrating my site to WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, migration, wordpress-theming, blogs

I recently migrated from php built website to Wordpress for my blog. And I after migrating I have observed a reduced number of traffic on my website. Even though the content is as generating good amount of ordinance on my fb page. The Google Analytic for my new Website show reduced amount of traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Using google analytics, look under Acquisition > Channels to see where you got the drop in traffic.

For example, if you got it in Organic Search, it could be because your old site had a different setup with Meta Titles, Descriptions, Keywords...

If you saw a drop in Direct traffic, it could be because you had a drop in spam traffic.

That should be a starting put to better answer your question.